# Implicit Differentiation and Tangent Lines (sin and cos)

Tags: calculus

a. verify that the given point lies on the curve.
b. determine an equation of the line tangent to the curve at the given point

function : $\cos{(x-y)}+\sin y = \sqrt{2}$

a. I derived it using implicit differentiation.
I got this: $$y' = -\frac{\sin(y-x)}{(-\sin{(y-x)}+\cos y)}; (\pi/2),(\pi/4)$$

So for a, to verify that the given point lies on the curve, I've gotta find the slope?

They provided the graph and I can verify the slope visually by using rise/run. However, Im confused on which slope to use- Do  I use $(\pi/4)/(\pi/2)$ as shown with the dimensions in the graph or do I use 1/2?

To verify this using the derivative, do I just plug in the points in $x$ and $y$ and see If i get this slope?

For b, Do I  use $y-(y)=m(x-(x)$? I plug in the two points plus the slope I find?